# Detach sentence-transformer model from GPU to cpu

Tags: python, gpu, cpu, sentence-transformers

I have trained a SentenceTransformer model  on a GPU and saved it. Now I would like to use it on a different machine that does not have a GPU, but I cannot find a way to load it on cpu.

```
from sentence_transformers import SentenceTransformer

model_name = 'all-MiniLM-L6-v2'
model = SentenceTransformer(model_name, device='cuda')
```

Answer (score 6):

Set  `device` parameter to `cpu`.

FYI : `device` takes as values  pytorch device (like cpu, cuda, cuda:0 etc.), By default it is set to `None`, checks if a GPU can be used.

```
from sentence_transformers import SentenceTransformer
model_name = 'all-MiniLM-L6-v2'
model = SentenceTransformer(model_name, device='cpu')
```

Answer (score 2):

You may need to install the CPU version of torch first.

`pip3 install torch --index-url https://download.pytorch.org/whl/cpu`

As shown here: https://pytorch.org/get-started/locally/

Note: With this version there is no need for the `device` argument either.